# PERL How to skip error in while loop

Tags: perl

I have this script which automates a process of like on Instagram.
It does exactly what it should do except for one thing. Within the while loop, if a user does not exist the script dies.
In this case, the error should be ignored and the script should continue processing the other users of the list.

This is the error i get:

`Error GETing https://www.instagram.com/usernamethatdoesntexist/?__
a=1: Not Found at instagram-post-liker.pl line 29`

Thanks for any help

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use JSON;


my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my $mech_get = WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0 Opera 12.14');


my $mecho = WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; de-de; HTC Desire HD 1.18.161.2 Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1');

$mecho->get('https://www.instagram.com/');

$mecho->add_header('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate', 'X-Instagram-AJAX' => '1', 'Accept-Language' => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2,nl;q=0.2' ,'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest', 'X-CSRFToken' => getcsrf($mecho));

my $post_data = {
    username    =>  'username',
    password    =>  'password'
};

$mecho->post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', $post_data);

  while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "getting user $row\n";

    $mech_get->get('https://www.instagram.com/'.$row.'/?__a=1');


    my $decoded_json = decode_json( $mech_get->response()->decoded_content() );

     print "Found Post \n";

    $mech_get->get('https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/'.$decoded_json->{user}->{media}->{nodes}[0]->{code}.'/');

    my $decoded_json2 = decode_json( $mech_get->response()->decoded_content() );

    print "Linking Post by Id";
    my $post;

    if($decoded_json2->{media_id} =~ /^([^_]*);*)   {
        $post = $1;
    }

    $mecho->add_header('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate', 'X-Instagram-AJAX' => '1', 'Accept-Language' => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2,nl;q=0.2' ,'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest', 'X-CSRFToken' => getcsrf($mecho));

    $mecho->post('https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/'.$post.'/like/');

}



sub getcsrf {

    my ($somemech) = @_;

    my $cookies2  = $somemech->response->header('Set-Cookie');


    my $csrf_token2;
    if ($cookies2 =~ /csrftoken=([^;]+);/i){
        return $1;
    }
    else {
        die "Unable to find csrftoken in cookie headers, did something change?";

        }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to use `eval` block

here's some documentation:
https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

Also, you forgot a `/` at `if($decoded_json2->{media_id} =~ /^([^_]*);*)`

your code will be then

```
#your code until line 29

eval {$mech_get->get('https://www.instagram.com/'.$row.'/?__a=1');};

if(not $@)
{
    my $decoded_json = decode_json( $mech_get->response()->decoded_content() );

     print "Found Post \n";

    $mech_get->get('https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/'.$decoded_json->{user}->{media}->{nodes}[0]->{code}.'/');

    my $decoded_json2 = decode_json( $mech_get->response()->decoded_content() );

    print "Linking Post by Id";
    my $post;

    if($decoded_json2->{media_id} =~ /^([^_]*);*)/   {
        $post = $1;
    }

    $mecho->add_header('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate', 'X-Instagram-AJAX' => '1', 'Accept-Language' => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2,nl;q=0.2' ,'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest', 'X-CSRFToken' => getcsrf($mecho));

    $mecho->post('https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/'.$post.'/like/');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day.

Comment: you're welcome ;)
Can you click on "accept as answer" if this worked for you? :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, any piece of code that may fail may be placed within an `eval` block like this:

```
eval {
  # Piece of code that may fail
};
if($@) {
  # In case you want to deal with the error; $@ contains the text describing the error
}
```

The piece of code inside `eval` will be compiled, so you know that it contains no syntax errors. A run-time error will be ignored but you will be able to catch it within the `if` block.

Comment: Thanks, this information will surely be useful for me in the future

Answer (score 0):

## Disable WWW::Mechanize's automatic error handling

WWW::Mechanize by default does automatic error checking, which dies on errors (http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.86/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#new()). You can add `autocheck => 0` to the constructor to disable this behaviour. You then have to check manually after each request, either by checking the return of the request method

```
my $response = $mech->get($url);
unless ($response->is_success) {
    ### add your error handling here
}
```

or by using WWW::Mechanize's shortcut:

```
$mech->get($url);
unless ($mech->success) {
    ### add your error handling here
}
```